# Shared wwwroot files in different projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

In the "older" ASP.NET MVC projects you were able to create two separate MVC projects. Use the first project as the "main" MVC project and let that project then reference the second project (with some additional config settings).

Basically how 3rd party MVC projects were setup. You reference their assemblies in your own MVC project and you auto-magically have "Admin" pages available as well.

I'm currently trying to find out if this is possible for the newer MVC ASP.NET 5 as well.

I basically have two projects. Both have their own `wwwroot` folder. Only the first start up project has an `index.html` in the `wwwroot` and the second project (which is referenced by the first) has an `index.html` in the subfolder `test`. So in the 2nd it is: `wwwroot/test/index.html`.

When I run the first project I want to be able to also call `localhost/test/index.html`.

But all my attempts failed so far. Anyone any idea if this is already possible?