# Share wwwroot across multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two ASP.NET Core MVC projects. Both projects have the same files in their `wwwroot` folders.

My question: is it possible to specify a custom location for the `wwwroot` folder, so that I could access the same `wwwroot` folder in both projects?

I have already read similar questions like:

- [ASP.Net Core: Use Shared Project to share static assets (css / js) between many projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651162/asp-net-core-use-shared-project-to-share-static-assets-css-js-between-many/62959226#62959226),
- [Share static files between ASP.NET Core Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703149/share-static-files-between-asp-net-core-projects),
- [Shared wwwroot files in different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061330/shared-wwwroot-files-in-different-projects),
- [Virtual directory inside of ASP.NET Core app in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030121/virtual-directory-inside-of-asp-net-core-app-in-iis)

With the help of the above listed questions, I identified two approaches

- using a virtual directory
- including the files using `app.UseFileServer`

However, I was not able to reference the files using relative paths, e.g. in `_Layout.html` the reference `~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` does not work.

Comment: you could use a CDN

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, the OP has made at least some effort to research before posting here

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom WebRoot path in Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
      {
         webBuilder.UseWebRoot("C:\path\to\folder");
         webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer for your question, but it helped me when I was looking for similar functionality, so leave it here for future seekers.
If you are using `ASP.NET Core 3.1`, you can use a RazorClassLibrary, which allows you to share your static files between different projects. There is a great explanation in below article
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/330/including-static-resources-in-razor-class-libraries-in-asp-net-core